# PIP Won't install Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I'm trying to install tensorflow with pip, but every time I try I get this:

```
pip3 install Tensorflow
Collecting Tensorflow
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Tensorflow 
(from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Tensorflow
```

What do I do?
(I'm running Pip 19.2.2 on Windows 7 x64 if this info is needed)

Comment: As always, you follow the [installation guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install)

Comment: Should 'tensorflow' be in all lowercase?

Comment: Run `python -c "from pip._internal.pep425tags import get_supported; print(get_supported()[0])"`, what output do you get?

Answer (score 2):

Try `python3 -m pip install tensorflow`

Also tensorflow only supports 64 bit version Python, check that you have installed the correct version.

Comment: Where would I download the 64 bit version of python?

Comment: @Lebster from official python website - python.org

Comment: for some reason I don't have the python3 command even after installing the latest 64 bit version, I only have the python command on its own

Comment: Are you sure that you installed python3 and not python2?

Answer (score 0):

Also, often times its easier to use a slightly older Python version together with Tensorflow. I have found installations of e.g. Python 3.6.x + tf to work more smoothly than 3.7.x.

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```